# Reference inheriting class in base class method?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I'm looking for the best way to provide a method in an (abstract) base class, which all inheriting classes should be able to use.
This method needs to reference fields and properties of the inheriting types.
Is there a way to provide such a prototype method which doesn't require me to either:

- Pass a reference to each inheriting instance in question
- Implement a method on each inheriting class which passes a reference to itself to the base class's method
- Write an extension method for implementing classes

All of the above work, but seem somewhat inconvenient and unelegant in their own way.

Here is an example where I implemented the three above methods of referencing the inheriting class:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public void ReferenceInheriting(object InheritingInstance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: " + InheritingInstance.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    public class Inheriting : BaseClass
    {
        public void MakeUseOfBaseClassImplementation()
        {
            base.ReferenceInheriting(this);
        }
    }
    
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void BeAvailableForAllImplementing(this BaseClass Inh)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: " + Inh.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    
    class program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Inheriting inh = new Inheriting();
            Console.WriteLine("Method 1: Calling the inherited method from an inheriting instance, passing a reference to the instance:");
            inh.ReferenceInheriting(inh);
            Console.WriteLine("Method 2: Implementing call to the base class's method in own class:");
            inh.MakeUseOfBaseClassImplementation();
            Console.WriteLine("Method 3: Extension method for all implementing classes:");
            inh.BeAvailableForAllImplementing();
        }
    }
}
```

The three approaches all produce the same output, but have drawbacks.
Short of parsing caller information, is there another way to do this?
It's not a big deal of course, but I'm interested in making this method as user friendly as possible, both for implementing inheritance and for calling.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is reflection being used here at all? Why doesn't `BaseClass` declare `getMe`, if it has a legitimate use for it?

Comment: As a side note: it would really help if you'd follow normal naming conventions, even for sample code. Anything unconventional is an additional distraction for people reading the question or trying to answer you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which aspects of naming convention are you referring to in particular? Of course the names may be a bit long, but I thought they were describing what I expect from them alright

Comment: @BenPhilipp: `reflectInheriting` should be `ReflectInheriting`, `getMe` should be `GetMe`, and so on. I don't think the problem is the length but rather the capitalization. It threw me off a bit, too.

Comment: @ThomasBonini Oh! I see

Comment: I find that *imagining* the problem someone is trying to solve is almost always inferior to actually being told what it is, especially when what they're looking for are solutions that are "elegant" and "convenient". For example, it matters a ton whether you're reflecting over *all* properties of a class, or *specific* properties, and then if these specific properties are always the same, or vary by instance. You could have an `abstract` method that returns `PropertyInfo`s, for example, or a base method that takes a `Func<TProp>`. Hard-coding `getMe` as a string is bad, even as a toy example.

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh, of course. In my mind, the problem this question is about (referencing inheriting class) was entirely separate from my final goals of the implementation (what I do when I got the reference), so I neglected to talk too much about the latter. (Note, however, that reflection is not part of the problem I was trying to solve) I'll edit the question for less confusion

Comment: Yes, if all you were *really* looking for was `this.GetType()` from a base class method and didn't know that worked, a lot of this is fluff. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fluff removed :) And yes, I didn't know that `this` inside a base method would always refer to the "final", possibly inheriting, object/instance. Thank you for your patience and insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of that.

This:

```
    public void reflectInheriting(object inheritingInstance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: " + inheritingInstance.GetType().Name);
        FieldInfo fi = inheritingInstance.GetType().GetField("getMe");
        Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(inheritingInstance));
    }
```

Can be rewritten as simply:

```
    public void reflectInheriting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: " + this.GetType().Name);
        FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField("getMe");
        Console.WriteLine(fi.GetValue(this));
    }
```

And that's all you need.

C# saves the actual underlying type of an object regardless of how it's cast, so even inside `BaseClass`, `this.GetType()` will be `Inheriting`.

---

Program output to prove nothing has changed:

> Method 1: Calling the inherited method from an inheriting instance, passing a reference to the instance:
>
> Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: Inheriting
>
> Use me in BaseClass
>
> ---
>
> Method 2: Implementing call to the base class's method in own class:
>
> Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof:
> Inheriting
>
> Use me in BaseClass
>
> ---
>
> Method 3: Extension method for all implementing classes:
>
> Do things specific to the inheriting class or instance thereof: Inheriting
>
> Use me in BaseClass

Comment: What the... That is such fundamental behavior, I can't believe I didn't know that's how it works! ‍♂️ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection, but that is kind of a weapon of last resort. The idiomatic way to access a property or method in a descendent class is to make it abstract in the base class.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void GetInheriting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetMe is: {0}", this.GetMe);
    }

    protected abstract string GetMe { get; }
}

public class Inheriting : BaseClass
{
    protected override string GetMe => "Use me in BaseClass"; 
    
    public void MakeUseOfBaseClassImplementation()
    {
        base.GetInheriting();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var o = new Inheriting();
        o.MakeUseOfBaseClassImplementation();
    }
}
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jm4RMb)

Output:

```
GetMe is: Use me in BaseClass
```

Comment: Reflection is part of what I want to do with the implementation in the first place. Note that I am not trying to use Reflection to get a reference to the class, and that it is not used to try to answer the question.  The actual implementation provides custom functionality to all inheriting classes and needs to get properties and fields from them

Comment: Fair enough... When someone asks a question, it's hard to tell how much they know and how much they don't, and I didn't want the "normal" approach to be missed. I'm sure you have good reasons to use Reflection.

Comment: I'm sorry to have caused some confusion, I thought I'd let part of my code in as an example of working with the inheriting class, but it seems that that was a bad idea  References to Reflection are now removed from my question. Thank you for your time and input, and sorry I wasn't clearer in my attempt to illustrate my question ^^